# Web deploy to IIS to a site application from tfs

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, tfsbuild, webdeploy, webdeploy-3.6

I am trying to have the tfs build server deploy a asp.net core site into and application of a .net framework asp.net web api site running iis.

I can get it to work if I create the asp.net core application as its own website sharing the same application folder.

I am calling the powershell script that visual studio generates when using web deploy.

The call it generates is

```
> "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"
> -source:manifest='C:\Users\BuildService\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\a\SourceManifest.xml'
> -dest:manifest='C:\Users\BuildService\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\a\DestinationManifest.xml',ComputerName='https://server:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Demo%20mainSite/dotnetCoreApp',UserName='username',Password='{{PASSWORD-REMOVED-FROM-LOG}}',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic'
> -verb:sync -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:20 -disablerule:BackupRule -allowUntrusted
```

The error received is

> Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZEDMore Information: Connected to the
>   remote computer ("server") using the Web Management Service, but could
>   not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and
>   password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the
>   credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site. 
>   Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.Error:
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.Error count:
>   1.

Which is either the site cannot be found or the username / password is wrong. As I mentioned the script when changing it to a site so it shouldn't be that unless I am missing a special permission the site application needs that the site doesn't.

The build definition

[image: The build definition]

The arguments string

```
-packOutput "$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" -publishProperties @{'WebPublishMethod'='MSDeploy';      'MSDeployServiceURL'='$(remoteUrl)'; 'DeployIisAppPath'='$(appName)';'UserName'='$(ausername)';'Password'="$(password)"; 'EnvironmentName'='$(environment)'; 'EnableMSDeployBackup'='$(backup)';'AllowUntrustedCertificate'='true'} -Verbose
```

Variables
[image: build variables]

The full log

```
2017-02-02T15:06:25.0517357Z . 'B:\_work\108\a\server-publish.ps1' -packOutput "B:\_work\108\a" -publishProperties @{'WebPublishMethod'='MSDeploy';      'MSDeployServiceURL'='https://server'; 'DeployIisAppPath'='Demo mainSite/dotnetCoreApp';'UserName'='username';'Password'="********"; 'EnvironmentName'='staging'; 'EnableMSDeployBackup'='false';'AllowUntrustedCertificate'='true'} -Verbose

2017-02-02T15:06:25.0547361Z Executing the following powershell script. (workingFolder = B:\_work\108\s)

2017-02-02T15:06:25.0547361Z B:\_work\108\a\server-publish.ps1 -packOutput "B:\_work\108\a" -publishProperties @{'WebPublishMethod'='MSDeploy';      'MSDeployServiceURL'='https://server'; 'DeployIisAppPath'='Demo mainSite/dotnetCoreApp';'UserName'='username';'Password'="********"; 'EnvironmentName'='staging'; 'EnableMSDeployBackup'='false';'AllowUntrustedCertificate'='true'} -Verbose

2017-02-02T15:06:25.6777700Z VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'B:\_work\108\a\publish-module.psm1'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7307946Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Register-AspnetPublishHandler'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7307946Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Get-AspnetPublishHandler'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7317771Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Publish-AspNet'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7327889Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Publish-AspNetMSDeploy'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7327889Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Publish-AspNetMSDeployPackage'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7337689Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Publish-AspNetFileSystem'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7337689Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Get-PropertiesFromPublishProfile'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7348209Z VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Get-MSDeploy'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7397836Z VERBOSE: Registering MSDeploy handler

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7607760Z VERBOSE: Adding handler for [MSDeploy]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7637948Z VERBOSE: Registering MSDeploy package handler

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7647892Z VERBOSE: Adding handler for [Package]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7657950Z VERBOSE: Registering FileSystem handler

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7667860Z VERBOSE: Adding handler for [FileSystem]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7677977Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-AspnetPublishHandler'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7677977Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-MSDeploy'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7687917Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-PropertiesFromPublishProfile'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7687917Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Publish-AspNet'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7697881Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Publish-AspNetFileSystem'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7707794Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Publish-AspNetMSDeploy'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7707794Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Publish-AspNetMSDeployPackage'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.7717769Z VERBOSE: Importing function 'Register-AspnetPublishHandler'.

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8108318Z Publishing with publish method [MSDeploy]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8558374Z VERBOSE: Adding default property to publishProperties ["SkipExtraFilesOnServer"="True"]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8587850Z VERBOSE: Adding default property to publishProperties ["retryAttempts"="20"]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8607935Z VERBOSE: Adding default property to publishProperties ["DeleteExistingFiles"="False"]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8618096Z VERBOSE: Adding default property to publishProperties ["MSDeployPackageContentFoldername"="website\"]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8638077Z VERBOSE: Adding default property to publishProperties ["AuthType"="Basic"]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8647915Z VERBOSE: Adding default property to publishProperties ["MSDeployUseChecksum"="False"]

2017-02-02T15:06:25.8658376Z VERBOSE: Adding default property to publishProperties ["MSDeployPublishMethod"="WMSVC"]

2017-02-02T15:06:26.1098668Z VERBOSE: Found msdeploy.exe at [C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe]

2017-02-02T15:06:26.1168709Z Executing command ["C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:manifest='C:\Users\BuildService\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\a\SourceManifest.xml' -dest:manifest='C:\Users\BuildService\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\a\DestinationManifest.xml',ComputerName='https://server:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=Demo%20mainSite/dotnetCoreApp',UserName='username',Password='{{PASSWORD-REMOVED-FROM-LOG}}',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:20 -disablerule:BackupRule -allowUntrusted]

2017-02-02T15:06:26.1218393Z VERBOSE: Found msdeploy.exe at [C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe]

2017-02-02T15:06:27.2510114Z Info: Using ID '7b0f156a-8f7a-4259-84df-93d9008e6f22' for connections to the remote server.

2017-02-02T15:06:27.2900134Z ##[error]Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZEDMore Information: Connected to the remote computer ("server") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.Error count: 1.

2017-02-02T15:06:27.2910140Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
```

Comment: Could you share your build definition? How did you deploy your project?

Comment: I added the images. Is there a way to show text or is that enough for you?

Comment: How about include the username and password in your script instead of argument?

Comment: Added the username and password to the script didn't work.

Comment: Can you publish the output successfully if you run the command manually?

Answer (score 1):

As [this website](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.Error) mentioned, ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED typically indicates an authentication or authorization problem, and can happen because of any of thee following reasons:

- User does not exist
- User does not have IIS Manager access to site if connecting using Web
  Management Service
- Site does not exist
- Password is incorrect

If connecting using the Web Management Service, make sure you have checked the resolutions below:

- Verify that the username and password are correct
- Verify that the site exists
- Verify that the user has IIS Manager Permissions to the site's scope

Also try the following steps:

- Select the website in IIS Manager
- Open up IIS Manager Permissions
- Verify that the user you are deploying as has been added. If not, click Allow User and add it.